# Resize LV's in a LUKS encrypted VG - Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: linux, filesystems, lvm, dm-crypt

I wanted to resize the FS on a machine but i ran into problems:

Purpose: the LV of /home is too big, the LV of / is too small (they're on 1 VG.) - I need to put 10 GByte from /home to /!!

Problem: gparted only shows this (can't see the LV's.. :):

[image]

How can I put 10 GByte to / from /home if they're encrypted with LUKS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GParted doesn't support LVM at all (unless this has changed recently?). You'll need to use the command line tools.

First, if you're booting from some rescue media, ensure that the volume group involved is active. The sequence will be something like

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 encrypted
pvscan
vgchange -ay /dev/mapper/my_volume_group
lvchange -ay /dev/mapper/my_volume_group-root /dev/mapper/my_volume_group-home
```

Then shrink the filesystem of the home volume. Use the right tool depending on the filesystem, e.g. `resize2fs` for ext2/ext3/ext4, `resize_reiserfs` for ReiserFS, …

Then resize the logical volumes, first shrinking `home` to make room, then expanding `root` to use the available space. Check the documentation for the units you can use with `lvreduce`.

```
lvreduce -L NEWSIZE /dev/mapper/my_volume_group-home
lvextend /dev/mapper/my_volume_group-root
```

Finally extend the filesystem of the root volume.